# External hard disk not working

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have Seagate 2 TB external Hard drive(**Seagate Backup Plus Slim**, to be exact). When I connect it to USB 2.0 port or eSATA port, it gets started spinning and beeps 2 times. Then it keep spinning for some time. Then it gets stopped. The light doesn't glow anywhere during the process. The hard drive is just 2 months old. Also I tested it on both Ubuntu and Windows 7 and on different laptops.

Answer (score 0):

#### When I connect it to USB 2.0 or eSATA port, it starts spinning and beeps 2 times.

It is possible that your drive is not getting enough power:

> Seagate and Maxtor-brand hard drives do not contain audio speakers.
> Some failure mechanisms may make a regular repeating beep from the
> computer's internal speaker. This may or not be hard drive related.
>
> Check your system documentation for an explanation of system beep
> codes. If a drive failure is possible, it is always important to make
> an immediate backup.

...

> **Troubleshooting noise issues for external drives:**
>
> External USB drive clicking and beeping can occur if the USB port does
> not provide enough power to operate the drive, often a USB 1.x port,
> or an unpowered USB hub. To resolve this noise, connect the drive with
> both of the USB connectors (if possible), or if your drive only has
> one connector, try connecting it to other USB ports on your computer.
> If that does not work, connect it to a powered USB hub to ensure
> enough electrical power.
>
> The Seagate Portable, Seagate FreeAgent Go Classic, and Maxtor
> OneTouch mini drives, in particular, included a USB Y-cable with two
> USB connectors so that, if one USB port did not power the drive
> enough, it could be connected to a second USB port.

Source [Identifying and troubleshooting hard drive noise issues](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/174571en?language=en_US)